# formatting output with for loop or different method in python

Tags: python

I did a program to calculate the inventory in python;however, i have problem formatting the layout output. What I have done so far is:

```
def summary(a,b,c,row,col,tot):
    d={0:"Small", 1:"Medium", 2:"Large", 3:"Xlarge"}
    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(col):
            print "%6d" %(a[i][j]),
        print "%s%6d\n" %(d[i],(b[i])),
    print "\n" ,
    for j in range(col):
        print "%6d" %(c[j]),
    print "%6d\n" %tot
```

so the output comes the 7 x 4 matrix and the total to the right hand side and by column total. However I want to put some names on the left hand side to represent the specific name like size small etc so i used a dictionary but what i am getting is on the right hand side just before the row total. I can't figure out how can i put it on the left hand side in the same row as the numbers. I want to put two columns apart from the number (matrix) which one would be a size in the first far left column in the middle and then in second column names as u can see specified used in dictionary and then the numbers would come in the same row.

Thanks a lot for any help or suggestions.  I did a program to calculate the inventory in python;however, i have problem formatting the layout output. What I have done so far is:

```
def summary(a,b,c,row,col,tot):
    d={0:"Small", 1:"Medium", 2:"Large", 3:"Xlarge"}
    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(col):
            print "%6d" %(a[i][j]),
        print "%s%6d\n" %(d[i],(b[i])),
    print "\n" ,
    for j in range(col):
        print "%6d" %(c[j]),
    print "%6d\n" %tot
```

so the output comes the 7 x 4 matrix and the total to the right hand side and by column total. However I want to put some names on the left hand side to represent the specific name like size small etc so i used a dictionary but what i am getting is on the right hand side just before the row total. I can't figure out how can i put it on the left hand side in the same row as the numbers. I want to put two columns apart from the number (matrix) which one would be a size in the first far left column in the middle and then in second column names as u can see specified used in dictionary and then the numbers would come in the same row.

Thanks a lot for any help or suggestions.

I want it to look like this

```
 small   1 1 1 1 1 1 1  7
 medium  1 1 1 1 1 1 1  7
```

size large   1 1 1 1 1 1 1  7

```
 xlarge  1 1 1 1 1 1 1  7
         4 4 4 4 4 4 4  28
```

and i get

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 small 7

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 medium 7

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 large 7

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 xlarge 7

4 4 4 4 4 4 4 28

sorry for not being specific enough previously.

Comment: Could you show us what you want the output to look like by actually producing an example by hand, and comparing to what you actually get?

Comment: Yeah, and please describe what this is for, and what a, b, c, row, col, and tot refer to.  What is their context?  When is this called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just print it before the row:

```
def summary(a,b,c,row,col,tot):
    d={0:"Small", 1:"Medium", 2:"Large", 3:"Xlarge"}
    for i in range(row):
        print d[i].ljust(6),
        for j in range(col):
            print "%6d" %(a[i][j]),
        print "%6d\n" %(b[i]),
    print "\n" ,
    for j in range(col):
        print "%6d" %(c[j]),
    print "%6d\n" %tot
```

This assumes you want the first column left justified. Right justification (`rjust()`) and centering (`center()`) are also available.

Also, since you're just using contiguous numeric indices, you can just use a list instead of a dictionary.

As a side note, more descriptive variables are never a bad thing. Also, according to [this](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html), % formatting is obsolete, and the `format()` method should be used in new programs.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to move the "%s" and the appropriate variable to the correct position:

```
def summary(a,b,c,row,col,tot):
    d={0:"Small", 1:"Medium", 2:"Large", 3:"Xlarge"}
    for i in range(row):
        print "%8s" % d[i],
        for j in range(col):
            print "%6d" %(a[i][j]),
        print "%6d\n" % ((b[i])),
    print "\n" ,
    print "%8s" % " ",
    for j in range(col):
        print "%6d" %(c[j]),
    print "%6d\n" %tot
```

When calling this with (note that this are just test-numbers, you will replace them with the real ones):

```
summary([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
         [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
         [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
         [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]], [12, 13, 14, 15], 
         [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28], 4, 7, 7777)
```

you get something like:

```
   Small      1      2      3      4      5      6      7     12
  Medium      1      2      3      4      5      6      7     13
   Large      1      2      3      4      5      6      7     14
  Xlarge      1      2      3      4      5      6      7     15

             22     23     24     25     26     27     28   7777
```

If you want the names left adjusted, you have to add a '-' before the format description like:

```
            print "%-8s" % d[i],
```